# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me apareza el primer día del mes actual y el día actual en Crystal report?

Tags: date, crystal-reports, report

Esto tengo hechos pero el resultado es el siguiente:
del 01/6.00/2,023.00 al 23/06/2023
Y tengo lo siguiente:

```
dateVar fecha := CurrentDate;
"del 01/" + ToText (Month (fecha)) + "/" + ToText (Year (fecha))+ " al " + ToText(fecha)
```

Comment: Ya quedo solucionado:

"DEL 01/" + ToText(CurrentDate, "MM") + "/" + ToText(CurrentDate, "yyyy")+ " AL " + ToText(CurrentDate)